# Facebook PHP SDK access token issue

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been having some issue getting the Facebook Graph API to work with tokens and **without redirects**. I am getting the token via URL, but facebook just won't recognise it. Here's the code:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => $details['app_id'],
    'app_secret' => $details['app_secret'],
    'default_graph_version' => $details['default_graph_version']
]);

$authToken = $this->helper->fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={$details['app_id']}&client_secret={$details['app_secret']}");

$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($authToken);

$response = $fb->get($page.'/posts');
```

And the error I get is a FacebookResponseException: **Invalid OAuth access token signature**.
At this point I'm certain this is not the right way to do it, but I can't find any documentation on what the proper way is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out i was trying to set the default token with the full returned string, which was *access_token=ACTUAL_TOKEN*.

Changing `$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($authToken);` to

```
$info = explode('=', $authToken);
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($info[1]);
```

resolved the issue.

**EDIT:**
Even better still, turns out you don't need to request a token for an app request like this, so this will also work:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => $details['app_id'],
    'app_secret' => $details['app_secret'],
    'default_graph_version' => $details['default_graph_version'],
    'default_access_token' => $details['app_id'].'|'.$details['app_secret']
]);

$response = $fb->get($page.'/posts');
```

Answer (score 0):

for facebook api v4  try this

i think this refo  https://github.com/codeNmind/facebook-php-sdk-v4 help you

```
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookSignedRequestFromInputHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookCanvasLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('APP-ID','APP-SECRET-KEY');

$helper = new FacebookCanvasLoginHelper();

try {
    $session = $helper->getSession();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}

if ($session) {
    try {
        $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
        $response = $request->execute();
        $me = $response->getGraphObject();
        echo $me->getProperty('name');
    } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('https://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAMESPACE/'); // add your Facebook app namespace here

    // getting the login url for your app
    $auth_url = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('email')); // add new permission here as an index type array

    // redirecting the user directly to your Facebook canvas app you can also make a link of it
    echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$auth_url."'</script>";
}
```